# Okhttp3+android has a significant delay between responseHeadersStart and responseHeadersEnd

Tags: android, networking, okhttp

I am using okhttp 4.0.1 in an Android app and there is a significant delay when receiving the response, particularly the headers. This adds a significant delay time to the users (ranging around 2-5 seconds) per request sent. The time delay is measured using okhttp's EventListenerfrom here https://square.github.io/okhttp/events/

This code is already placed inside an AsyncTask. Note that the delay happens after `mCall?.execute`

```
        val mBuilder = Request.Builder()  
        val url = ....
        // Add URL
        mBuilder.url(url) // Request.Builder

        // Request
        val req = mBuilder.build()

        // Call
        var resp: Response? = null
        var code = RESPSTATUS_IOEXC
        var body = ""
        try {
            // Execute the call
            mCall = mClient.newCall(req)
            resp = mCall?.execute()
            code = resp?.code?: 0
            body = resp?.body?.string()?: ""
        } catch (e: ConnectException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            code = RESPSTATUS_CONNECTION_FAILED
        } catch (e: SocketTimeoutException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            code = RESPSTATUS_TIMEOUT
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            code = RESPSTATUS_IOEXC
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            code = RESPSTATUS_ALREADY_EXEC
        } catch (e: CertificateException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            code = RESPSTATUS_INVALID_CERT
        } finally {
            resp?.close()
        }
```

One of the example messages showing the delay (3s delay retrieving response headers):

```
[1] dns started!
[1] dns ended!
[1] connect started!
[29] secure connect started!
[46] secure connect ended!
[46] connect ended!
[46] connection acquired!
[46] request headers started!
[47] request headers ended!
[47] response headers started!
[3676] response headers ended!
[3676] response body started!
[3702] response body ended!
[3704] connection released!
[3704] call ended!
```

Sample of the response headers I am getting

```
------ header(Server): nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
------ header(Date): Thu, 08 Aug 2019 15:08:02 GMT
------ header(Content-Type): application/json
------ header(Content-Length): 33071
------ header(Connection): close
------ header(Vary): Content-Type
------ header(Strict-Transport-Security): max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload;
```

Our iOS team has called the URLs given without any considerable delay (1-2s max), so I do not know if the problem lies in the code or the server itself.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks before

Comment: What numbers do you get when you hit a static page, like https://www.google.com/robots.txt ?

Comment: Using google.com/robots.txt, I get a very small delay.

```
[1] connection acquired!
[1] request headers started!
[3] request headers ended!
[3] response headers started!
[41] response headers ended!
[41] response body started!
[42] response body ended!
[42] connection released!
[42] call ended!
```

Comment: This suggests Google's webserver can respond in 38 milliseconds. Your webserver is slower than Google's.

Comment: Have you had any update on this?
I´m facing the same problem!